# why is the notation for sums and integrals so different?

Tags: notation

An integral over some set $A$ is typically written
$$\int_A f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$$
whereas a sum over a set $A$ is written
$$
\sum_{i\in A} f(i).
$$

To me, these "feel" different. Why not write integrals like
$$
\int_{\mathrm{d}x\in A} f(x)
$$
or sums like
$$
\sum_A f(i) \mathrm{d} i?
$$

Sometimes one might see something like
$$
\int_A f(i) \mathrm{d}\#(i)
$$
where $\#$ is the counting measure which is sort of a middle ground.

Comment: some inspiration for notation comes from Riemann sums, where you are finding $$\sum_{i \in A} f(i) \Delta x_i \to \int_A f(x)dx$$

Comment: The symbols ∫ and Σ do have the commonality of connoting "S for sum", but in different alphabets.

Comment: For example, the $\int$ is similar to the [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)